# Disable Automatic adjusting font for UILabel,UIText,etc. in iOS/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift4

Go to "Settings"-> "General"-> "Accessibility"-> "Larger Text" to change the font size.
Open my app, now all the UILabels and UIButtons do change accordingly. I want to disable it and want to keep as it is regardless of the large font or small font on the setting. I have made everything programmatically. How can I disable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971292/enable-disable-font-scaling-impact-by-ios-on-my-application

Comment: 1st I am not using storyboards. 2nd. I am unable to DISABLE it not enable that.

Answer (score 0):

`myLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = false`

Although this depends on the font that you're using. See more info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategoryadjusting/1771731-adjustsfontforcontentsizecategor?language=objc.

Specifically, this part:

> For this property to take effect, the element’s font must be vended
>   one of the following ways:
>
> - It must be vended using the preferredFontForTextStyle: or
>     preferredFontForTextStyle:compatibleWithTraitCollection: method with a
>     valid text style.
> - It must be vended using one of the scaling methods from UIFontMetrics.